# Multiple implementations of Google ReCaptcha on a single page

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have multiple implementations of Google's invisible reCaptcha on a single page.

Sometimes there is an alert that appears saying "cannot contact recaptcha check your connection and try again".

I believe this is because you are not supposed to call request recaptcha multiple times.

Is there any way to circumvent this, either by using all 3 forms with one instance of recaptcha, or by allowing multiple requests in some way.

If not, is there an alternative solution to reCaptcha to protect multiple forms on a single page?

The method I am using is async defer on the JS with a callback to my own function which initializes the recaptcha for each form.

You can see in the network log that each initialization causes 3 requests to google each.

Thanks